# React native - How to wrap a View with Text?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

Like the screenshot above, I wish to wrap the View (8.5) with the Text.

This is what I have tried :

```
 <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}>
     <View style={{backgroundColor:'grey', padding:5, borderRadius:5, flexWrap:'wrap'}>
         <Text style={{fontSize:12, fontWeight:'bold'}>
            {item.score}
         </Text>
     </View>
     <Text style={{fontSize:14, fontWeight:'bold', color:'black'}>{item.title}</Text>
 </View>
```

Above code, Text does not wrap the score view, but positioned side by side like below:

[image]

How do I make sure that the view is wrapped by the Text? Thanks

---- Edit
@Gaurav Roy's answer yields following result, which styles does not apply to Text component except background color

[image]

Answer (score 0):

'ive made the changes , try these, this will work :

```
 return (
    <View style={{marginTop:5}}>
   <Text>
         <Text style={{fontSize:12, fontWeight:'bold',backgroundColor:'grey', padding:5, borderRadius:5, flexWrap:'wrap',marginRight:5}}>8.5</Text>
  
     <Text style={{fontSize:14, fontWeight:'bold', color:'black',lineHeight:20}}>thisis a good example of how things acan be cahieved in the lord of the rings</Text>
     </Text>
 </View>
  );
```

It looks like this

[image]

also you cna check the live example at [live example](https://snack.expo.io/z3nh0RUIO)

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your solution seems to work on web, but not on ios or android unfortunately. Padding does not get applied on Text component

Comment: strange, whats the problem there? can you send a ss?

Comment: you can check through the live example you have posted. Can you have a look through android / ios instead of web? can't seem to post image in comment

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe try this:

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "flex-start" }}>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, fontWeight: "bold", color: "black" }}>
    <View
      style={{ backgroundColor: "grey", padding: 5, borderRadius: 5 }}
    >
      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 12,
          fontWeight: "bold"
        }}
      >
        8.5
      </Text>
    </View>
    this is a good example of how things can be achieved in the lord of
    the rings
  </Text>
</View>
```